# Is there a way to call a specific javascript function in a single js file for a specific page URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a question, i wanted to know if there is a way to call a specific function if a specific page URL is opened?

- #shop_modal is in http://myurl/liste-boutique.php
- #dep_modal is in http://myurl/index.php

Right now, i have Error when i try to open the #dep_modal because JS cant find #shop_modal on that page same page, so it does not execute below that.

I think AJAX can help figuring this out, otherwise i will have to split the code in 2 JS files, which i don't want to

```
const new_shop = $("#new_shop")[0];
const save_shop = $("#shop_form")[0];
const close_shop_modal = $("#close_shop_modal")[0];


const new_departement = $("#new_dep")[0];
const save_departement = $("#dep_form")[0];
const close_dep_modal = $("#close_dep_modal")[0];

// I want this to be called if the URL is http://my-URL/liste-boutique.php
new_shop.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $("#shop_modal")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
})

// I want this to be called if the URL is http://my-URL/index.php
new_departement.addEventListener('click', function(){
    $("#dep_modal")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
})
```

i need to ask question, but i don't know what to change here
Thanks again !!

Comment: Yes, sorry, i edited it, thanks for the info :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check `window.location.href`. E.g.

```js
if (window.location.href === 'http://my-URL/liste-boutique.php') {
    new_shop.addEventListener('click', function(){
        $("#shop_modal")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking the url, check if the element you want to find is on the page:

```
var $new_shop = $("#new_shop");
if ($new_shop.length > 0) {
    var new_shop = $new_shop[0];
    new_shop.addEventListener('click', function(){
        $("#shop_modal")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    })
}
```

(I've used `$` prefix on `$new_shop` to show it's a jquery object just for clarity)

Or, using your code as-is:

```
var new_shop = $("#new_shop")[0];
if (new_shop != undefined) {
    new_shop.addEventListener...
```

Alternatively, if you use jquery, you don't need to worry about it as it will automatically not apply if the element doesn't exist:

```
 $("#new_shop").click(() => { $("#shop_modal)").fadeIn(); });
```